# libgluezilla not found installing a program with wine

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, wine

I trying to install a program in ubuntu with wine and when I put the command in the termina apears the following error: libgluezilla not found. To have webbrowser support, you need libgluezilla installed

I saw other questions of stack overflow which tells that have to install the package libmono-webbrowser4.0-cil what I have already done but the error still happen. Any clue?